# Problem installing vineyard from terminal

Tags: root

I cannot install `vineyard` because I am asked this:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>."
```

See "man sudo_root" for details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running: `apt install 1232`  run `sudo apt install 1232`. You will be prompted to enter your password and you must be in the group `sudo` or have permission to use the command in the sudoers file to be able to run `sudo`